# How can I set a variable linear gradient colour?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass, attr

I am using a pure css version of 'clamping' as from this link inspired by Chris Coyier:
http://codepen.io/bental/pen/JWEaJg

This means I have css (sass) such as:

```
.clamp:after {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
}
```

Sometimes the background is not white, so what I want to do is set the second colour to a variable colour.

I can only think of two options which I don't think work. This is what I've tried:

- Use inherit to get the parents background colour
- Use JS (Angular) to write to the :after element, and set the background property, which I don't think I can do in Angular
- Use the attr(data-something) property to access an attribute on the parent which I can set in Angular

Neither work for me. Does anyone know how I can set a linear gradient on a pseudo element (in this case :after)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheriting way actually works.
http://codepen.io/blackmiaool/pen/dvNqQM

Change the css as below:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 1.2em/1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.module {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), red 50%);
}
.module p {
  margin: 0;
  background:red;
}


.fade {
  position: relative;
  height: 3.6em; /* exactly three lines */
}
.fade:after {
  content: "";
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Works well, but I don't have the p inside the element, i can inject a span or something inline, but out of interest, can you see a way without the p tag there?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros I don't actually understant what you want, maybe a div wrapper can help?

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Now I know what you want is to achieve this function with a single dom. You can do this by adding "box-shadow: inset 10000px 0px red;" to the .module dom;

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Sass, you could stick the background colour in a variable? For example:

```
$background-color: #eee;

.special-div {
  background: $background-color;
  .clamp:after {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), $background-color 50%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but I need to change that $background-color variable dynamically. e.g. some special-divs are blue, some are red

Answer (score 0):

if you can replace **pseudo element** with **span** you can change color dynamically

```js
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller("myColor",function($scope){
var background="linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%)";
$(".cover").css("background",background);
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font: 1.2em/1.2em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.module {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.module p {
  margin: 0;
}


.fade {
  position: relative;
  height: 3.6em; /* exactly three lines */
}
.cover{
 text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
    <div class="module fade" ng-controller="myColor">
  <p >Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <span class="cover"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```